# PyQt4 - deployment with py2exe mail, reportlab.pdfgen

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, py2exe

I'm trying to deploy a small pyqt4 app which uses the following modules: 'email', 'reportlab.pdfgen', pypdf , standard pyqt stuff (interface: custom widgets).

Here is the setup.py I use:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
console=['main.py'], 
options={
    "py2exe":
    {
        "includes":["sip",'lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 
        'gzip', 'email.Encoders', 'email.Generator', 'email.Iterators', 
        'email.MIMEBase', 'email.MIMEMultipart', 'email.MIMEText', 'email.Utils', 'email.base64MIME',
        'pyPdf.PdfFileWriter', 'pyPdf.PdfFileReader', 'reportlab.pdfgen', 'reportlab.lib.pagesizes'  ]
    }
})
```

At first when compiling, I got errors that some of the above modules are missing. But now, it compiles just fine, but when I try to run the program all I get is a black console window. At one point, I managed to get my program running, but when trying to send mail, or generate a PDF, it would just fail without any errors.

I switched to Python and pyqt because I thought it would give me a leaner development time. I never thought deploying would give me such headaches.

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? What are you looking for beyond someone to make it work (which isn't really possible without a [MCVE])

Comment: I'm just trying to find out, if someone who used py2exe and any of the mentioned modules stumbled upon the same issues and found a solution. The app is working just fine in python (launched from the command line with python main.py...) Thanks

Comment: I'll try to provide a verifiable example. Thanks